# Episerver PropertyList having Url type property does not storing data when upgraded to Episerver 11.3.1 which was working properly earlier in 10.10.1

Tags: episerver

We are using PropertyList and which is working properly till we upgrade Episerver version to 11.3.1 from 10.10.1.

Here is the code snippet -

```
public class PropertyListBase<T> : PropertyList<T>
{
    protected override T ParseItem(string value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }

    public override PropertyData ParseToObject(string value)
    {
        ParseToSelf(value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Property class-

```
[PropertyDefinitionTypePlugIn]
public class PropertySliderList : PropertyListBase<Slider>
{

}


public class Slider
{

        /// <summary>
        /// Slide image in Carousel 
        /// </summary>
        [UIHint(UIHint.Image)]
        public ContentReference Image { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Display position of the slide in Carousel
        /// </summary>
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Can be any link that to be associated with image in Carousel
        /// </summary>
        public Url AssociatedUrl { get; set; }

}
```

In the block there is property to store multiple slides-

```
public virtual IList<Slider> SliderBlock { get; set; }
```

When we tried to add slides in the block, it does not save value for AssociatedUrl property.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This has been resolved. Refer the article for more details- https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2017/12/new-propertylistlttgt-episerver-11/